# Converting List to Comma Separated String in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have below scenario, where two operations need to be performed. One is parsing the list and create a comma separated string. Then, transform that into the output format json

Input -

```
{
   "list": ["ABC","XYZ"]
}
```

Output -

```
{
  "additionalAttributes" : {
    "userContext" : [ {
      "auths" : "ABC,XYZ"
    } ]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this spec

```
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "list": "=join(',',@(1,list))"
    }
  }, {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "list": "additionalAttributes.userContext[].auths"
    }
  }
]
```